# Hex increment / loop till FFF

Tags: c#, asp.net, hex

I have an string which contains a hexadezimal number and i want to increment that hex number until i reach my max number (FFF). How can i loop through so i can get every number between my start hex and FFF?

I tried to convert the string in a byte array but got stuck after that.

```
string stringHex = "7A";
string binaryval = "";
binaryval = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(stringHex, 16), 2);
int numOfBytes = binaryval.Length / 8;
byte[] bytes = new byte[numOfBytes];

for (int i = 0; i < numOfBytes; ++i)
{
    bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(binaryval.Substring(8 * i, 8), 2);
}
```

I need this to create a table which displays all those numbers.

Solution:

```
        string sHex = Convert.ToString(sIPv4.Split(':')[2]);

        for( int intFromHex = int.Parse(sHex, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);intFromHex <= 4095; intFromHex++)//4095 - FFF
        {
            string hexValue = intFromHex.ToString("X");
            //SQL INSERT
        }
```

Comment: Convert to `int` -> increment `int` -> convert to hex.

Comment: What do you mean by "*I want to increment that number*"?

Comment: why do you work with `int` insted of `bytes` ?

Comment: loop through, so i get 7A,7B,7C,... and so on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert `String` to `Int` increment the `Int` and then convert it back to `String`(Hex)

```
string stringHex = "7A";

int intFromHex = int.Parse(stringHex , System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber) + 1;

string hexValue = intFromHex.ToString("X");
```